# Profiling Power consumption on ARM for C program

Tags: c, embedded, arm

I have multiple C programs each doing the same piece of functionality.
I want to evaluate/calculate which of these has a lower power consumption( on ARM)
Is there some tool(simulator) with which I can simulate and get the number of power
consumed and compare the same for each of the programs on desktop?

Based on this I will decide which of these apps I will finally put on the ARM.

Comment: Why do you have to do this the complicated way?  Can you not just load each program onto real hardware and monitor the current draw from the power supply?

Comment: @MartinJames: This may not be seahorse's reason, but automatic tuning would certainly need some way to do this in an automated way.

Comment: Do take into account that different ARM implementations will have different power consumption profiles.

Comment: I don't have the hardware with me, it's a proof of concept app and I need to simulate and prove that the power consumption is really low.

Comment: @Dan Can you (or others) point me to some examples, where multiple programs doing the same piece of functionality have different power consumptions? I am curious to see some examples.

Comment: @Venkatesh - dwelch's answer pretty much sums it up - if the power consumption is different, something (H/W, S/W, external interfaces) is different.  For example, the same 2 programs running on different processor architectures (e.g. MSP430, Intel i7) will consume very different amounts of power.  Change the compiler, the interrupts, the compiler /options/, etc. and that can change again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is not something you can simply model and run, you would have to know the exact core and gate switches, etc and the apply that to the cell library and on and on. If you work with/for the company making the chip then ask the silicon team they might have a tool for that otherwise you have to measure power differences on a pcboard running the code on real chips. The arm rtl and the cell library properties are not available to the general public only folks that have paid for those items

Answer (score 1):

[This tool](http://www.arm.com/products/tools/software-tools/rvds/arm-profiler.php) looks quite promising. It is part of the [ARM RVDS 4.0 Pro](http://www.arm.com/products/DevTools/RVDSPro.html).

It does non-intrusive performance profiling. It is propriety though. So it may be expensive. But there is a trial version too, which gives you about a month of free use.

If you are using gcc-arm, you can also try the [GNU Profiler](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html).

Comment: The GNU Profiler has nothing to do with power-usage profiling, nor with simulation.  Based on the website, it does not appear that the ARM tool you mentioned has anything to do with power usage either.